Keycloak Login IP Overriding In session
I have a web server , app server and a keycloak server. whenever Login take place I can see Event session Ip address of my app server. for audit report purpose I am in need of user Ip instead of app server Ip
I have tried to bind user ip in x-forwarded for of httpHeaders and then pointed keycloak server through rest template. but not worked.
Also tired with authenticate spi context - header - updating ip . got error
unable to figure out any document on this.  can anyone help me with that.
